# IOS uses css to make repeated animation, which flashes when the repetition starts

Tags: css

When the ios terminal uses css to do repeated animation beyond the screen, it will flash at the beginning of the repetition

I tried

-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;

```
    <div class="box">
        <div class="content-box" v-for="(item, index) in [1, 1]">
            <div v-for="(listitem, listindex) in list" class="list-item">
                {{listitem.text}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   <style>
        .box {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          animation: test 8s linear 0s infinite normal;
        }
        .content-box {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          min-width: 100vw;
        }
        .list-item {
          white-space: nowrap;
          padding: 10px 24px;
    
          margin-right: 20px;
          background: #F5F6F9;
          border-radius: 32px;
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          align-items: center;
          justify-content: center;
        }
   </style>
```

Comment: We really can't help without seeing the relevant code - any answer at the moment will just be a guess. Please create an example which we can run to see the problem for ourselves. See  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: thanks your help, i have code the relevant code and i added   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;  to .box, added -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0); to .content-box and .list-item  ,then fixed it. only in ios has this question